# How to remove linear contribution of timeseries from a reference timeseries?

Tags: regression, time-series, python

I have four timeseries and one of which is a reference timeseries . My objective is to remove the influence of the reference timeseries from Series 1, 2,... and 9, respectively, by using their linear regression. In the end, I will have new Series 1, 2,... and 9 that are "free" from the influence of the reference timeseries. How do I do this in python? I have basic knowledge in using Jupyter.

[Link to the data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kLDATCUFuIS2_kBkXsAwdLncUgccVqp9/view?usp=sharing)

Thank you in advance.